# Recovering unstaged files from git

Tags: git, recover

I was trying to convert my project from SVN to GIT as a few suggested it would be better. So setting it up for the first commit was a bit different. However, I couldn't understand what it was trying to accomplish using SourceTree. Under the unstaged files it had a list of all of the files to add. I was trying to ignore some of the extensions I wouldn't be using. After not understanding it I tried to cancel the changes so I wouldn't commit all these files that I didn't need. Apparently 'discard changes' to GIT meant return everything to original and since I didn't commit anything that means wipe the entire project. So now my entire project is just gone EXCEPT the extensions of files I IGNORED in .gitignore. I see that there is a .git folder with a bunch of objects. It seems pretty sizeable, so hopefully my project still resides there, is there anyway to recover these?

Comment: At least you still have SVN to work with, though, right…?

Comment: If it is a pristine repository, there won't be any commits to reset back to. Can you do a `git log` and post here the output.